# modify multiple observations in a by variable

Tags: sas

```
data a1

col1 col2 flag
a    2    .
b    3    .
a    4    .
c    1    .
```

For data `a1`, `flag` is always missing. I want to update multiple rows using `a2`.

```
data a2

col1 flag
a    1
```

Ideal output:

```
col1 col2 flag
a    2    1
b    3    .
a    4    1
c    1    .
```

But this doesn't update all the records in `by` statement.

```
data a1;
modify a1 a2;
by col1;
run;
```

**Question edited**

Actually `a1` is a very large data set on server. Hence I prefer to modify it (if possible) instead of creating a new one. Otherwise I have to drop previous `a1` first and copy a new `a1` from local to server, which will take much more time.

Comment: Note: `col1` in `a1` is not sorted. And I don't want to sort it (it's already sorted by other columns).

Comment: Just seen this comment - if it's sorted by other variables you could just put them all in the SQL `order by` to keep the same order

Comment: According to the [modify documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0g9jfr4x5hgsfn17gtma5547lt1.htm), you should be able to `If there are duplicate values of the indexed variable in the master data set, only the first occurrence is retrieved, modified, or replaced. Use a DO LOOP to execute a SET statement with the KEY= option multiple times to update all duplicates with the transaction value.`. I have not figured out how yet though.

Comment: If you are using the second form of the statement that is.

Comment: @D.Josefsson look like a DoW loop

Comment: @W_ee, yes it does. But when I try it, it does not iterate through `a1` as I expects it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with MODIFY, you have to loop over the modify dataset in some fashion or it will only replace the first row (because the other dataset will then run out of records - normally this behaves like merge, where once it finds a match it advances to next record).  Here's one option - there are others.

```
data a1(index=(col1));
  input col1 $ col2 flag;
datalines;
a    2    .
b    3    .
a    4    .
c    1    .
;;;;
run;

data a2(index=(col1));
  col1='a'; 
  flag=1;
run;

data a1;
    set a2(rename=flag=flag2);
    do _n_ = 1 to nobs_a1;
      modify a1 key=col1 nobs=nobs_a1;
      if _iorc_=0 then do;
        flag=flag2;
        replace;
      end;
    end;
    if _iorc_=%sysrc(_DSENOM) then _error_=0;
run;
```

Comment: If `a1` is not indexed, then `key` statement will return error.

Comment: Yes, you need an index (as you see in my answer).

Comment: It seems to take a little bit time to create an index on a large dataset.

Comment: Of course. Though once you do so it shouldn't be a problem to keep it up to date.

Comment: I think that or proc SQL will be the same. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Merge statement for the sorting problem, you can simply change your merging approach.
If flag in A1 is always missing, you can drop it, otherwise you should temporary rename it for not losing those informations.
Here I will merge A1 and A2 using hash objects, this approach doesn't require any prior sorting on datasets.

```
data final_merged(drop = finder);
length flag 8.; /*please change length with the real one, use $ if char*/
if _N_ = 1 then do;
            declare hash merger(dataset:'A2');
            merger.definekey('col1');
            merger.DefineData ('flag');
            merger.definedone();
end;
set A1(drop=flag);
finder = merger.find();
if finder ne 0 then flag = .; 
/*then flag='' or then flag='unknown' as you want if flag is a character var*/
run;
```

Please, let me know if this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following but SQL sorts the observations so not sure how useful this would be for you? (you could always preprocess with `ordvar=_n_;` and then sort the SQL statement on it if that helps):

Data:

```
data a1 ;
input col1 $ col2 flag ;
cards ;
a 2 .
b 3 .
a 4 .
c 1 .
;run ;

data a2 ;
input col1 $ flag ;
cards ;
a 1 
;run ;
```

Merge:

```
proc sql ;
create table output as
  select a.col1, a.col2, b.flag
  from a1 a
  left join
  a2 b
  on a.col1=b.col1
;quit ;
```

Comment: Question edited. Could you take a look at the new one? (actually I just want to avoid creating a new dataset).

Comment: Ah I see - I'll post it as an alternative answer in case this is still of use to anyone else

Answer (score 0):

To try and do it in one pass, how about creating two macros variables containing the mapping from `a2`?

```
proc sql ;
select distinct col1, flag
into :colvals separated by '', :flagvals separated by ''
from a2
;quit ;
```

Set flag to the corresponding character position between the two macro variables:

```
data a1 ;
  set a1 ;
  if findc("&colvals",col1) then 
    flag=input(substr("&flagvals", findc("&colvals",col1),1),8.) ;
run ;
```